# How to count digits in BigDecimal?

Tags: biginteger, bigdecimal, java

I’m dealing with `BigDecimal` in Java and I need to make 2 check against `BigDecimal` fields in my DTO:

1. Number of digits of full part (before point) < 15
2. Total number of
   digits < 32 including scale (zeros after point)

What is the best way to implement it? I extremely don’t want `toBigInteger().toString()` and `.toString()`

Comment: The `toString` approach (maybe with some `indexOf(".")`) would probably by **far** the easiest. Is there a specific reason to not use it? (Sure, it does not look elegant, and there may be approaches with better performance, but I'm sure there are many caveats when trying to figure this out manually...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work.

```java
      BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("921229392299229.2922929292920000");
      int fractionCount = d.scale();
      System.out.println(fractionCount);
      int wholeCount = (int) (Math.ceil(Math.log10(d.longValue())));
      System.out.println(wholeCount);
```

I did some testing of the above method vs using `indexOf` and subtracting `lengths of strings`.  The above seems to be signficantly faster **if** my testing methodology is reasonable.  Here is how I tested it.

```java
      Random r = new Random(29);
      int nRuns = 1_000_000;
      // create a list of 1 million BigDecimals 

      List<BigDecimal> testData = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int j = 0; j < nRuns; j++) {

         String wholePart = r.ints(r.nextInt(15) + 1, 0, 10).mapToObj(
               String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining());

         String fractionalPart = r.ints(r.nextInt(31) + 1, 0, 10).mapToObj(
               String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining());

         BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(wholePart + "." + fractionalPart);
         testData.add(d);
      }

      long start = System.nanoTime();
      // Using math
      for (BigDecimal d : testData) {
         int fractionCount = d.scale();
         int wholeCount = (int) (Math.ceil(Math.log10(d.longValue())));
      }

      long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
      System.out.println(time / 1_000_000.);

      start = System.nanoTime();
      //Using strings
      for (BigDecimal d : testData) {
         String sd = d.toPlainString();
         int n = sd.indexOf(".");
         int m = sd.length() - n - 1;
      }

      time = System.nanoTime() - start;
      System.out.println(time / 1_000_000.);
   }
```

Comment: Hi thank you, I really like you answer! One thing is I need to know the total number of digits including scale, not only scale. Does it mean that the total number of digits is equal to fractionCount + wholeCount or can it be in another way?

Comment: Yes.  fractionCount + totalCount.  And by scale. I presume you mean trailing zeroes, which the scale() method of BigDecimal seemed to include.

Comment: Great! Thank you. Maybe rate my question?

Comment: It fails on 12345678901234567890123456789012 and I had to use int wholeCount = amount.toBigInteger().toString().length();

Comment: I thought you said the whole part was supposed to be less than 15 digits in your question.  That number is too big for a long.  There is no decimal point.